# Block migration of exact duplicates

Tags: feature-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317034/usage-of-hyper-visor-when-running-windows-phone-apps was originally posted on SO.

[Use of Hyper Visor to run the Windows Phone Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320936/use-of-hyper-visor-to-run-the-windows-phone-emulator) has an **identical** body and was cross-posted to  http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com before being migrated to SO.

Migration should not be allowed when there is already a question on the target site with an identical body posted by the same user.

Comment: It's called *cross-posting*. Cross-posted questions should be closed as off-topic on one site, linking to the cross-post. If this happens again, instead of closing as a duplicate, we should close as off-topic so that the migration is marked *rejected*.

Comment: I know it's called cross-posting - I used that exact term in my original post. The point is that allowing a question to be migrated to a site when an exact duplicate already exists there (whether open or closed) creates needless work for the users of the destination site (they have to handle the duplicate). If the system automatically prevented the migration (so the only action possible on the source site would be to close the question), that extra work would not be required.

Comment: This is why cross-posting is not allowed. But a technical prevention would be nice. However, this would have to be server-side, so I think it should be an automatic rejection after the necessary 5 votes are reached, rather than preventing from voting as this would incur a huge hit on the server.

Comment: Perhaps it could be checked for only after the necessary votes are cast on the source site. At that time, if a duplicate exists on the target site the migration would be automatically rejected and the copy on the source site would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Nah.  What should happen is the question is migrated, then the migrated post is merged with the crosspost.  This isn't done automatically, but the person who arranged the migration can flag to have them merged.  Happens all the time (unless policies have changed).  This saves answers, and the signpost pointing to the question is now correct.